# ¿Cómo verificar si dos archivos son realmente el mismo?

Tags: python

Necesito comparar dos cadenas que indican nombres de archivo y ver si efectivamente están apuntando al mismo. De entrada podríamos intentar compararlas, pero tiene su complejidad, por ejemplo:

```
fname1 = "prueba.txt"
fname2 = "Prueba.txt"
```

¿Se trata del mismo archivo? En Windows podríamos llegar a decir que sí, en Linux obviamente No (Notar la P en mayúscula de uno de ellos). Por lo que mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna forma dados dos paths absolutos de, saber si se trata del mismo archivo? que además sea consistente entre sistemas operativos. Aclaración: las cadenas siempre apuntan a archivos reales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291504/6836377) explica como comparar dos archivos y saber si son los mismos. La idea entonces, es usar [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) que nos retorna un objeto [`stat_result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) con información de cada archivo, los datos que nos importan son: `st_ino` el número del inodo en Unix, o bien el índice del archivo en Windows, y `st_dev` que es índice del dispositivo dónde se aloja el archivo.

```
import os

def are_same_files(fname1, fname2):
  stat1 = os.stat(fname1)
  stat2 = os.stat(fname2)

  return True if stat1.st_ino == stat2.st_ino and stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev else False

print(are_same_files("c:\autoexc.bat", "C:\AUTOEXEC.BAT"))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si dos archivos son iguales debes de comparar su hash, cualquier otro método no te asegura al 100% que así sea. Cuando te descargas un archivo en internet, te suelen dar el hash (checksum) para que compruebes que lo que te has descargado es el archivo original y no cualquier otro.

Para ello:

```
import hashlib

def sha256sum(filename):
    h  = hashlib.sha256()
    b  = bytearray(128*1024)
    mv = memoryview(b)
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        for n in iter(lambda : f.readinto(mv), 0):
            h.update(mv[:n])
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Y llamando a la función `sha256sum(filename)` puedes obtener el hash de un archivo para comparar ambos.

Comment: Gracias, Jota. Pero mi pregunta apunta para otro lado. No quiero saber si dos archivos físicamente distintos tienen el mismo contenido. Lo que busco es: si dados dos nombres de archivos, como saber si apuntan al mismo archivo físico.